# Await multiple promises but complete them as they the finish

Tags: lightning-web-components

So say for example I wanted to grab three lists of data I could do an await all for each get I'd need to do then display the information like below.

```
const promise1 = this.getOrders();
const promise2 = this.getAccounts();
const promise3 = this.getOpportunities();

const results = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);

this.doStuff(results);
```

But actually what if promise1 takes 20 seconds to complete compared to the others that take only 1 second I don't want the other two lists to be empty for no reason as I already have the data is there any way I can pull add the data from the faster two promises as they complete.

Comment: Are the promises depends on each other for the response?

Comment: no completely unrelated I just want it in a list so that I can show the users that X promises are pending

Answer (score 0):

Promises can only resolve once, which is why `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled`, and `await` work like they do. if you don't care about the order, then don't use `Promise.all`.

```
this.getOrders().then((result)=>this.doStuff1(result));
this.getAccounts().then((result)=>this.doStuff2(result));
this.getOpportunities().then((result)=>this.doStuff3(result));
```

Edit:

Based on the comments, I show how you can execute multiple promises and keep track of them separately. Here, I create a list of values that can add arbitrary functions with increasing timeouts so you can observe the effects.

```
  addAction() {
    const delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); // 0-9 second delay
    this.executeAction((resolve)=>setTimeout(resolve, delay*1000), `${delay} Second Loading Time`);
  }
  clearDone() {
    this.statuses = this.statuses.filter((status)=>status.state !== 'Done!');
  }
  executeAction(action, name) {
    const state = 'Pending';
    const id = `id-${this.#guid++}`;
    this.statuses.push({ id, name, state });
    new Promise(action).then(()=>{ this.statuses.find((status)=>status.id===id).state = 'Done!' }).catch(e=>console.log(e));
  }
```

Here, in the `executeAction` function, we can pass in any function that accepts the `resolve` and `reject` parameters that a Promise normally takes, and then update the status when we're done. We can also pass a message through `resolve` or `reject` as normal.

[Demo](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/vZvttiHWzPB9AAEbLMVR/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: it just feels really untidy and I want to beable to show a pending list to the user and I want to beable to add extra promises as we go along if I could have a list of promises that work that way it would be much better >_>

Comment: @Tythus You can, you just have to build it yourself. I created a sample for you to look at.